# Can anyone see what is causing the page to render wider than the browser in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

I know questions like this get short shrift on here for not containing actual code but I have been banging my head against a wall for over 2 hours here.

If you browse the site,  you can see the site sits 100% width in the good browsers, but in ie11 when on the home page there is a horizontal scrollbar,  something is stretching it beyond the browser width.  I have taken things out systematically but it is driving me insane?

http://ag.splatwebsolutions.co.uk

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is in this style.

```
.site{
   display:table;
}
```

using [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) might help